# Openssl pkcs8 default format gives RSA PRIVATE KEY

Tags: openssl, rsa

I'm running this command on my pc (Openssl version: 1.0.1) :

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key -passin pass:12345678a -outform PEM -out key.pem
```

and i got this key.pem:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmEwggJdAgEAAoGBANCFPVXwO+6qQdOs
...
wVauPfh0cGEf1Kc=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But when i run the same command it from my server (Openssl version: 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5) i get this output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQDQhT1V8DvuqkHTrMPFUUAXUl0ihDGoiD86SqK8Z3n19yp1VrJf
...
zHY0343VXnpM2opKwG2E1zgfHfbcLMFWrj34dHBhH9Sn
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The Base64 inside is differente and also the headers:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The first one works for me, how could i get the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- output on the 0.9.8 version?

I found this on OpenSsl patch notes:

> Change default private key format to PKCS#8.

so, that could be the main issue, i hope someone could help me with this, i dont find the way to get the private key but not the BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY one.

Thanks

Comment: It may help you http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html.

Answer (score 31):

Do `openssl pkcs8 -topk8` to convert a private key from traditional format to pkcs#8 format.

This format

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is referred to as "SSLeay format" or "traditional format" for private key.

I'm not sure which format your key is, so I'll demonstrate the idea with a private key generated by `genrsa`.
When you do `genrsa` in OpenSSL 0.9.8x, the generated key is in traditional format. That is, after

```
openssl genrsa -out file.key 1024
```

you'll get a rsa key in traditional format

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICWwIBAAKBgQC3TyaSzsJO92/Ahq5rxRI1T0JSC0iF...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then do `pkcs8` with `-topk8` to convert this key from traditional format to pkcs#8 format.

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem
```

Here's what you'll get:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BA...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

All of the above are done with OpenSSL 0.9.8x. It tells you how to generate PKCS#8 format key from the traditional format key.
On the other hand, you can always run this on OpenSSL 1.0.1 to make the key compatible with the older version:

```
openssl rsa -in file.pem -text > key.pem
```

Comment: thank you, it worked for me, i added the second proc and now it runs

Comment: On the last item `-text` is not needed; just read into `openssl rsa` and write out produces the "legacy" (PKCS#1) format as requested. `-text` *adds* human-readable comments that may be helpful in some cases, but they are not in the output formerly produced by `pkcs8` (from8) as the question requests.

Comment: Just for completeness, `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` is a PKCS#1 encoding where the data does not include the type of key. PKCS#8 can encode any type of key, but PKCS#1 does not include the type of key, thus the text header indicates the key type.

Comment: @LawrenceDol: PKCS #1 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2) doesn't specify any ASCII base64 encoding, and it also doesn't specify the `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` header. Do you have a link to a standard which specifies this header?

Comment: @pts: the (generic) header+base64+linebreaks+trailer format comes from PEM (RFC1421 4.3.2.4 and 4.4); there is no standard for OpenSSL 'traditional' formats `{RSA,DSA,EC} PRIVATE KEY`, although for RSA the content is PKCS1, ECC is SEC1 or RFC5915 and DSA is just EAY's choice. The 'new' (PKCS8) formats `PRIVATE KEY` and `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` are specified in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468 sections 10 and 11, referencing RFC5208 and RFC5958.